# Scrollable OL3 LayerSwitcher on mobile

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, scroll, openlayers-3

I'm migrating a web map from OL2x to OL3.  I've started with the OpenGeo web app builder (thanks, Boundless!) and have a functional map.... except for the layerswitcher on Chrome and Firefox on my Android phone and tablet.  My map has a large-ish number of layers and so the layerswitcher needs to be scrollable for the user to see all of the layers.  The scrolling behavior **is** working as expected on Chrome and Edge on a Windows Desktop machine.  I have a temporary version of the app here: http://rainpursuit.org/ol3/

Here's the CSS that I've tried for the LS "container"

```
.layer-switcher {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3.5em;
    right: 0.5em;
    text-align: left;
}
```

And for the "layer-tree-panel"

```
.layer-tree-panel {
    padding-right: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    background-color: white;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 0;
    translateZ: (0);
    -webkit-translateZ: (0);
}
```

Any suggestions on how to make this scrollable on touch devices that don't have a mouse to hover over the LS divs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the web map builder uses an early version of the [ol3-layerswitcher](https://github.com/walkermatt/ol3-layerswitcher), see [this issue](https://github.com/walkermatt/ol3-layerswitcher/issues/18) which resulted in scrolling being  fixed on touch devices. The [examples in the repo](https://github.com/walkermatt/ol3-layerswitcher#examples) include one for scrolling.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the LS with the world and your comments here!